# how to generate the merged list of values from JSON in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input Data in a json file:

```
[{
    "Orders": {
        "orderid": {
            "path": "order_id",
            "type": "CHAR",
            "is_explode_required": "N"
        },
        "customerId": {
            "path": "customers.customerId",
            "type": "CHAR",
            "is_explode_required": "N"
        },
        "offerid": {
            "path": "Offers.Offerid",
            "type": "LIST",
            "is_explode_required": "Y"
        }
    },
    "products": {
        "productid": {
            "path": "product_id",
            "type": "CHAR",
            "is_explode_required": "N"
        },
        "productName": {
            "path": "products.productname",
            "type": "CHAR",
            "is_explode_required": "N"
        }
    }
}]
```

In this output, for Orders, i want to get two column one with all values concatenated by comma
and the other column with values where is_explore_required is mentioned Y

```
output| exlode_output
order_id,customers.customerId,Offers.Offerid|Offers.Offerid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
df.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|Orders                                                                           |products                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|{{N, customers.customerId, CHAR}, {Y, Offers.Offerid, LIST}, {N, order_id, CHAR}}|{{N, products.productname, CHAR}, {N, product_id, CHAR}}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
val columName = "Orders".toLowerCase
```

```
val outputExpr = s"""
    concat_ws(
        ',', 
        transform(
            map_entries(
                ${columName}), 
                e -> e.value.path
            )
        ) AS output
    """
```

```
val explodeOutputExpr = s"""
    concat_ws(
        ',', 
        transform(
            map_entries(
                map_filter(
                    ${columName}, 
                    (k,v) -> v.is_explode_required == 'Y'
                )
            ), 
            e -> e.value.path
        )
    ) AS exlode_output
    """
```

```
val schema = "map<string, struct<is_explode_required:string,path:string,type:string>>"
```

```
df
.withColumn(
  columName, 
  expr(
   s"""
     from_json(
        to_json(${columName}), 
        '${schema}'
     )
    """
  )
)
.selectExpr(
   outputExpr, 
   explodeOutputExpr
)
.show(false)
```

```
+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
|output                                      |exlode_output |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
|customers.customerId,Offers.Offerid,order_id|Offers.Offerid|
+--------------------------------------------+--------------+
```